# How can i use log4j2 in weblogic?

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, log4j2

I have a problem when using log4j2 in weblogic. I built a war module which has a log4j-core-2.0.jar. My war has web-services annotated with @Webservice.

After i deployed my war into Weblogic, i can use web-services but i can not monitor them at weblogic configuration screen. I tried removing log4j-core-2.0.jar from my war module, then i could see my web-services.

How can i solve this bug?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean "monitor them at weblogic configuration screen"? The Deployments link? Is your server set to use log4j on the Logging tab? Hard to tell what you're asking

Comment: under deployments menu we can see deployed applications. When I enlarge my web application, normally, i can see web services which are annotated by @WebService but i can't see any web service if i have log4j-core-2.0.jar under WEB-INF/lib directory

Answer (score 1):

Please check the log4j2 FAQ on which jars to include. You need the api jar, the core jar, and possibly other bridge jars if other libraries in your app are coded to the log4j-1.x or logback APIs.

Also make sure to remove the log4j-1.x and logback *implementation* jars: the bridge jars will delegate to the log4j2 core implementation. Other implementations in the classpath may cause problems.